# Java Path ImageIcon URL .JAR

Tags: java, url, path, embedded-resource, imageicon

I may have made of try, none works..

The file is:

```
/Users/Toto/Desktop/Titi/IUT/Java/TP2/project/src/fichierPointJava/img1.png
```

`fichierPointJava` is the name of the package .

I launch the ant when I am situated in project which contains the build.xml

Here are the codes that I tested:

```
URL urlImage1=this.getClass().getClassLoader.getResource("/src/fichierPointJava/img1.png");
URL urlImage1=this.getClass().getClassLoader.getResource("/fichierPointJava/img1.png");
URL urlImage1=this.getClass().getClassLoader.getResource("fichierPointJava/img1.png");
URL urlImage1=this.getClass().getClassLoader.getResource("/img1.png");
URL urlImage1=this.getClass().getClassLoader.getResource("img1.png");

System.out.println("Value = "+ urlImage1);
```

I made out a will with or without `this`, and with or without `getClassLoader()`

Hope someone will help me.

Thanks you

Comment: Are you sure its in your jar? I would open it up and verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the following package layout

```
+---src
    |   img0.png
    \---fichierPointJava
        |       img1.png
        |       <YourClass.java>
```

then the the following should work

```
// using the classloader in instance context
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("img0.png");
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fichierPointJava/img1.png");

// using the classloader in class/static context
<YourClass>.class.getClassLoader().getResource("img0.png");
<YourClass>.class.getClassLoader().getResource("fichierPointJava/img1.png");

// using the class in instance context
getClass().getResource("../img0.png");
getClass().getResource("/img0.png");
getClass().getResource("img1.png");
getClass().getResource("/fichierPointJava/img1.png");

// using the class in static/class context
<YourClass>.class.getResource("../img0.png");
<YourClass>.class.getResource("/img0.png");
<YourClass>.class.getResource("img1.png");
<YourClass>.class.getResource("/fichierPointJava/img1.png");
```

When using the `ClassLoader` you need to pass the full qualified name of the resource, i.e including the package name.

When using the `Class` then the path - if not starting with `/` - is relative to the package where the class which is trying to load the resource is located, otherwise it is the absolute name of the resource.

You can read more about [ClassLoader#getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) and [Class#getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) in the javadocs.

Make sure that the ant target you are running to create the jar include the `*.png` resources. You can verify this by opening the jar with the zip-tool of your choice. The directory `src` should not be included.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't works ..

URL         urlImage1=getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fichierPointJava/img1.png");
        System.out.println("Value = "+ urlImage1);

It prints "null"

Comment: @AymenZero then check that the images are packaged into the jar file!

Comment: Have you checked the file is in your jar? What does `jar tvf YourFile.jar` output?

Comment: 0 Tue Jun 04 20:49:28 CEST 2013 META-INF/
   143 Tue Jun 04 20:49:26 CEST 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Tue Jun 04 20:49:24 CEST 2013 fichierPointJava/
  1398 Tue Jun 04 20:49:24 CEST 2013 fichierPointJava/Femme$1.class
  5332 Tue Jun 04 20:49:24 CEST 2013 fichierPointJava/Femme.class

Yeah , there is not the file into the jar file . So , i have to do it into the build.xml ? Or Something ?

Thanks you all for you help

Comment: @AymenZero please edit your question and post the xml-snipet coresponding to the target for creating the jar.

Comment: I did it ! Thanks you for telling me i forgot the files ..
It was this line to add : <fileset dir="${src.dir}/fichierPointJava">

Comment: It's just possible to tell me what returns getClass().getClassLoader().getResource ?
I think getClass returns the main class ?
getClassLoader humm ?
getResource returns the file ?

Comment: @AymenZero `getClass()` return the class object representing the actual class (`this`), `getClassLoader()` returns the class loader user to load the that class, a classloader has knowledge about the `classpath` and is able to find resource and load them, `.class`-files are also resources. when you rung a java app and specify a classpath using one of the switches `-cp` or `-classpath` then this information goes to the class loader. Basically you tell the jvm "to find the stuff (resources) that my app needs, then look here and there"...

Comment: @AymenZero Finally `getResource()` is the method you call to retrieve the location of the resources yo you can access it, obviously the return value is an `URL`, see the links i posted at the end of my answer. You may also want to have a look at [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) witch return an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) witch you can use to read your resource.