# Read a .txt file in a package

Tags: java, file-io

I would like to read from a .txt file from inside a package. To read it straight from where the file is located on the computer it works, but from the package it won't. I have used class loaders before but I am not very sure about how to use them if that is the answer. 
This opens the file and reads it line by line.

ReadTextFile.class

```
    public void readFile(String fileLocation){

try{
      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      String strLine;
      //Read File Line By Line
      while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
}
catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
}
}
```

This is in my other class to say what file to read.

```
    ReadTextFile textFile;
    textFile = new ReadTextFile();
    textFile.readFile("src/com/game/level_" + level + ".txt");
```

If I run this as a jar file outside eclipse I get this error.

```
Error: src\com\game\level_1.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

All my classes are in the same package as each other and so is the .txt file.
How can I read the .txt file from within the package.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: "[...] from the package it won't." Mind elaborate? What happens? Errors?

Comment: Sorry forgot. Added it now.

Comment: OP probably means read filed from class path, please have a look at [Class#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) and remove `src` from `"src/com/game/level_" + level + ".txt"`

Comment: Read it thanks but unfortunately no. Tried removing "src" or "src/" and no luck.

Comment: Never reference src, once built, the directory will not be available

Comment: How can I write it without "src"? It just comes up saying that it cannot find the file if I put "/com/game/level_" + level + ".txt"" or "com/game/level_" + level + ".txt"". Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: Please make sure that the file you are trying to read is present in the artifact you create (jar/war/ear...) or the directory where you compiled classes go to (with respect to the package). `src` is just where your source file are located and is not part of the package, once source code is compiled this directory is no longer present. Also there is no need for `DataInputStream`, just feed the `fstream` directly to the `InputStreamReader` constructor.

Comment: Okay it is definitely inside the .jar file after compiling it. That makes sense but I can't get it to work at all even in eclipse when I remove "src".

Comment: Try using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAstream("com/game/level_" + level + ".txt")`

Comment: It says this for the "getResourceAsStream" part. "The method getResourceAstream(String) is undefined for the type ClassLoader"

Comment: Probably a typo, the type `ClassLoader` has such a method, see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)). Also have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16925160/1113392) for more help

Comment: Corrected the typo. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Could it be because I am using FileInputStream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
package com.game;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        new MyClass().readLevel(1);
    }

    private void readLevel(int i) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("com/game/level_" + i + ".txt");
                BufferedReader br = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
            String line;
            while(null != (line = br.readLine())) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Output is (sample text content)

```
level 1
hello
```

If it doesn't then please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Tested Code Sample](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215383/191550)

Comment: Works absolutely perfect! Thank you very much as this has taken me so long!