# How to distribute a java GUI builder project

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, compilation, builder

Currently others i distribute to get "A Java Exception has occurred" from the java run time environment. How would I go about distributing this properly as a .jar?

```
package my.onis;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class onis extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    public onis()
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    public int oxygen = 100;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        btn = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        pb = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("One Night In Space");
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setResizable(false);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowActivated(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1135, 633));
        jPanel1.setLayout(null);

        btn.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\rando_000\\Desktop\\butt.png")); // NOI18N
        btn.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(200, 100));
        btn.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                btnMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(btn);
        btn.setBounds(430, 200, 200, 100);

        pb.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        pb.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 51));
        pb.setValue(oxygen);
        pb.setBorderPainted(false);
        pb.setFocusable(false);
        pb.setStringPainted(true);
        jPanel1.add(pb);
        pb.setBounds(30, 564, 280, 30);

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\rando_000\\Desktop\\Background.jpeg")); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(jLabel2);
        jLabel2.setBounds(0, 0, 1051, 633);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1051, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                 
        try{BufferedImage image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\rando_000\\Desktop\\butt.png"));
        boolean transparent = (image.getRGB(evt.getX(),evt.getY()) & 0x00ffffff)==0;
        if(!transparent)
        {
            mousePressed(evt);
        }}catch(IOException e){};
    }                                

    private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
        check();
    }                                    
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
    {
    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && oxygen > 0)
    {
            oxygen -= 10;
    }
    else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3 && oxygen < 100)
    {
        oxygen += 10;
    }
    }
    public void startUpdating()
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
        {

            pb.setValue(oxygen);

            if (oxygen <= 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You have died.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            try{sleep(10);}catch(InterruptedException e){};
        }
    }
    public void check()
    {
        Thread update = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                startUpdating();
            }
        };
        update.start();
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(onis.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(onis.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(onis.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(onis.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new onis().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel btn;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    public javax.swing.JProgressBar pb;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Here is a screenshot to show my project files and classpath

[image]

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace? Add it to your question.

Comment: This: `catch(IOException e){};` is one of the worst things you could place in a Java program. Seriously. Always handle your exceptions. Always.

Comment: Your GUI accesses image files as Files from hard-coded file paths,and I'm sure that your friend's computers don't have the same paths. Don't do this but instead package your images with your jar file and access them as resources not as files. If you search this site, you will find out how to do this. And again, handle your exceptions because this is likely blinding you and your friends from the actual source of the error. Your empty catch blocks are not a nice thing to give to your friends.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - Very good points.  However answering a question using comments isn't very helpful to anyone other than the OP.

Comment: @StuPointerException: I started to write an answer, but I'm at work and don't have time to write what I would consider an adequate answer I'm afraid including handling and placement of the resources. If you do have the time, however I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments below your question, the most obvious cause of the error is that the resources you are relying on are referenced using an absolute address.  This basically means that your program will be invalid unless the client has exactly the same configuration as your development machine.

To make your application distributable you should package the resources into the JAR file.  This question has some useful pointers:

[Java Path ImageIcon URL .JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924347/java-path-imageicon-url-jar)

As an aside, the stacktrace that is thrown when an exception occurs is invaluable when it comes to diagnosing errors.  You should definitely post it along with any further question on SO.  Don't swallow exceptions with code like this:

```
try {
    doSomethingWhichMightFail();
} catch(Exception e) {

}
```

Unless you're absolutely sure that the exception is inconsequential (which is very rare!).